# use vue-cli output in php project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-cli

When I use vue-cli, I'll automatically create a local server.

My question is: Can I use the vue-cli output in php project (for example,  app.js ) ?

What is the local network for? Is it going to help Frontend programmers?

I know, "devDependencies" (which probably includes this local server) did not work effectively in the final file.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vue-cli gives you a simple HTTP server running on nodejs which is called Node.js static file server. It's main purpose is to help developers at development time.

For production you need a production server like Apache Web Server.

Whether you need PHP or not depends on your application's nature. Many apps require server side rendering.  If so, you need PHP. If not, just copy the dist folder's content to Apache Web Server's hosting folder.